# Find all files matching a name and change to their route

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to make a simple script that walks over a directory tree searching for files named "plot.plt", change to their route and execute gnuplot inside that directory (because otherwise it drops an error).

I've tried this so far:

```
find . -type f -name "*.plt" -printf "%h\n" | xargs -i cd "{}"
```

But tells me that the directory does not exist.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `cd` is a shell built-in, `xargs` doesn't use the shell to execute its commands. And even if it did, it would be in a subprocess, so it wouldn't affect your original shell.

Comment: What do you mean by _change to their route_? It looks like you mean _change to its containing directory_.

Comment: Yes, sorry. it's containing directory so I can execute gnuplot inside, copy the  resulting image into a folder and cd to the original working directory then.

Comment: there shouldn't be any problem to invoke a program in different directory. what problem do you have? you need for loop here.

Comment: I thought I could do it only by using find utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute `bash` explicitly, since `xargs` doesn't run a shell. You need to perform both the `cd` and `gnuplot` in that shell invocation, because directory changes don't affect the parent process.

```
find . -type f -name '*.plt' -printf '%h\n' | xargs -i bash -c 'cd "$0"; gnuplot' {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with a small additional script (that you can also use as alias), you can do

`find . -iname "*.plt" -exec ./gnuplotcd {} \;`

the file gnuplotcd containing

```
#!/bin/bash
cd `dirname $1`
gnuplot `basename $1`
```

Dont forget `chmod +x gnuplotcd`.